# are there tools on linux similar to matlab .fig files and it is possible to modify the pic mannually?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matlab-figure

I'm using python's `matplotlib`, but I can't modify the generated pictures mannually. Which is very inconvenient.

Are there any tools which are similar to `matlab`'s plot functionalities so that it is possible to modify the pic mannually?

for example, I may want to modify the position of a legend. If I do it on scripts, then it could be troublesome coz I have to modify the position number for many times to get what I want. But if I can mannually move the legend in the picture, then it is very convenient.

BTW:
I tried:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
...
leg1 = ax1.legend(loc=(ax1_pos.x0+0.5, ax1_pos.y0+0.5))
leg2 = ax2.legend(loc=(ax2_pos.x0+0.5, ax2_pos.y0+0.25))

leg1.draggable(True)
leg2.draggable(True)
```

why can I only drag leg2 but not leg1?

Also if I want to modify the label, title, it is also more convenient to modify them on the picture rather than on the scripts.

Comment: What, specifically, is it that you want to do?

Comment: @TheBlackCat  I have added more details, pls check them. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to modify many matplotlib plot parameters in the figure, depending on the backend.  I use the Qt backend, and there is an option in the upper-right of the toolbar that lets me set colors, labels, titles, padding, etc.

For the legend, by default it cannot be moved.  But you can make it draggable by doing something like this:

```
leg = plot.legend('test') # this is where you create the legend
leg.draggable(True)  # this allows you to move the legend by dragging
```

Most basic properties can either be set in the interface, or can be configured to be easily manipulated.

Comment: this is in Python? but it is only about legend? how about other components?

Comment: and I have two legend, as explained in the original question, why can I only drag one of them?

Comment: Yes, this is matplotlib and python.  I can't really help you modify properties unless I know which specific ones you want to modify.  All the ones you listed so far can be modified directly in the figure.  As for multiple legends, you would probably need to set them all to be draggable in the manner I showed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). It's a free software that does the job very well. The bad side is that it doesn't really have a good interface with python (there is one but apparently it doesn't work very well and it lacks in docs). The bright side is that you can open your data in the command, modify it on-the-fly (using the `wxt` terminal; you'll see) and then save the output as you see it. I think that, in some ways, it's superior do `matplotlib`.